# How to regex string and match keys with values?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to regex capture following string into three different groups, ie **url**, **status** and **limit**. Below is the string that I wish to capture

```
url:https://test.com:status:200:limit:100
```

In a sense, I would like something:

```php
$string = 'url:https://test.com:status:200:limit:100'; // string
$regex = regex_match('/regex/', $string, $matches); // regex
$i = 0; // counter
$array = array(); //array

foreach($matches as $match)
{
   array_push($match['url'] => $match)
   $i++;
}
```

So that it would produce an array that consists of this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => https://test.com
            [status] => 200
            [limit] => 100
        )

)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match-all.php) function to search for all the matches in the string `url:https://test.com:status:200:limit:100` and place these matches in `$matches` array.

No need for looping, just pass the `$matches` array to the `preg_match_all` function and it'll do the task for you.

About the `regular expression` that could be used, `url:(?P<url>.+):status:(?P<status>.+):limit:(?P<limit>.*)` looks good. The `?P<name>`, where `name` is something like `url`, is a named capture group which help us to get the `name`s (e.g `url`) as the keys in the `$matches` array **BUT** it'll be mixed with the default numeric ones.

We can filter the `$matches` array using the built-in [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-filter.php) function to get only the non-numeric keys (such `url`, `limit`).

```php
$string = 'url:https://test.com:status:200:limit:100';
preg_match_all('~url:(?P<url>.+):status:(?P<status>.+):limit:(?P<limit>.*)~', $string, $matches); /** populates matches **/
$matches = array_filter($matches, function($k) {
    return !is_numeric($k);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY); /** filters the array **/
echo print_r($matches);
```

And you'll get something like :

```
Array
(
    [url] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://test.com
        )

    [status] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
        )

    [limit] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
        )

)
```

Now, you can get the url by using `$matches['url'][0]; /** https://test.com **/`.

In the end, here's a [live demo](https://3v4l.org/mXC8W).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the strings of the parts upfront, you could also use [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and list the parts you want to split on in an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|`

Instead of returning an array, you could use [list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to assign the values to variables.

```
$string = 'url:https://test.com:status:200:limit:100';
$pattern = "~(?:url|:status|:limit):~";
list($url, $status, $limit) = preg_split($pattern, $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/E4WCj)